# How to populate Custom UIView in swift 2?

Tags: ios, swift

I am new to swift and iOS development, and its quite confusing! I come from web development environment using php, mysql and html (a smarter environment ;) )

My goal here is to list data in cool design not typical table view, so I am using a custom class "CardView" that I found on the internet:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
public class CardView: UIView {

@IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 2

@IBInspectable var shadowOffsetWidth: Int = 0
@IBInspectable var shadowOffsetHeight: Int = 3
@IBInspectable var shadowColor: UIColor? = UIColor.blackColor()
@IBInspectable var shadowOpacity: Float = 0.5

override public func layoutSubviews() {
    layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
    let shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: cornerRadius)

    layer.masksToBounds = false
    layer.shadowColor = shadowColor?.CGColor
    layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: shadowOffsetWidth, height: shadowOffsetHeight);
    layer.shadowOpacity = shadowOpacity
    layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.CGPath
}

}
```

I added the CardView as framework, played around with it in storyboard.
I made a card with my preferences of shadow and border-radius, now I want to get serious and render each data set in a card, and list all cards vertically.

[image]

I included the CardView class to my ViewController, now what? :)
How to begin I am confused.. 
I know I need a class to take array of data, then loop through the array, and print each data inside a CardVeiw object.

I am just not sure how to make that!
totally new mac user, and new to xcode.

Comment: I´m confused. Why not use a tableview with Custom Tableviewcells?

Comment: I did not know that I can make the cards look out of Tableviewcells!?
will it be the same?

Comment: Yes you can style custom tableviewcells as views with nearly no restrictions

Comment: alright, thanks bro!

Comment: no problem, good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your next steps are:

1. Change your UIView to a UITableViewCell
2. Add everything necessary for a UITableViewCell Class
3. Add a Tableview to your ViewController and load the CustomTableViewCells in this TableView

For everything above there are a lot tutorials out there. I hope this helps.

There are no limits. You won't get a normal tableview if you use your own CustomCells.

Comment: just wondering, how it works if someone want to make a brave new design in iOS?

Comment: what do you mean with a brave new design? If you go even further ( i don't think you need it for your project) you can try out custom collectionviews for even more stuff. If that is still not enough you must do everything by yourself, but i think thats a lot of work.

Comment: yes not for this project, for future reference I meant. because I am planing to start app development and I have good web design skills, so I am planning to do apps with unique designs in future